# How to insert additional data (inserting time periods without data) into an Excel spreadsheet to create more accurate line graphs?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, linegraph

First of all, sorry for the badly worded question, I'm struggling to describe exactly what I'm looking for in a concise way.

I have a spreadsheet which essentially lists the amount of customer requests per month of a given request type (child description), over a three year period.

[image: A screenshot of part of the spreadsheet]

Using PivotTables, I've been able to summarise this data and create a line graph to display trends over time; this allows me with the click of a button to display a new graph for any of the child descriptions I want, as seen below:

[image: A screenshot of the PivotTable and Line Graph]

However, a problem arises with some of the request types - not all request types receive customer requests each month, and thus the data I was given is missing those months. It doesn't say '0', it simply isn't there. As seen in the image below, the line graph is a misrepresentation of reality, as there are no 0's, the graph doesn't tell the true story, and can't be used for decision making:

[image: Problem graph]

**My question is, is there a way to insert the months without data into my spreadsheet in a way other than manually entering it?**

Manual data entry is not an option, as I have hundreds of different requests types, and I aim to set this up so I can update it as new data comes in.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give this article a read, I think this can get you where you want to go.  http://www.excel-university.com/show-pivottable-months-without-data/

Comment: @ChrisMoore That article was about fixing the problem of making months with 0 transactions appear in the pivot table when the original dataset has the months in it; my dataset doesn't even have the month in it - the data will go Jan - 3 requests, Feb - 57 requests, Mar - 8 requests. There is no April. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think  you might be looking at the output and not the starting data.  The article shows how to get April to 0 when there are no April entries.

Comment: @ChrisMoore - got it mate, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by Chris Moore, I worked out how to solve my issue.

On the PivotTable, I needed to right click and select 'Field Settings' and select the box 'Show items with no data':

[image]

Then I right clicked the PivotTable again and selected 'PivotTable Options', and formatted it so that 'For empty cells show:' was 0:

[image]